# Extracting QuickTime mov_text subtitles with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, subtitles

I have a `.mov` file that has `mov_text`-formatted subtitle tracks that were created using the old (now deprecated) QuickTime 7 Pro's "Text Track" feature. This is what `ffmpeg -i myfile.mov` tells me about them:

```
  Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574), 640x116, 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 0
      creation_time   : 2021-11-20T03:08:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Text Media Handler
```

Currently I still have access to QuickTime 7 Pro, where I can extract the subtitles to then convert to SubRip or some other format that can be read by other programs.  However, I need to update my system and QuickTime 7 Pro doesn't run on macOS Catalina and above, so I am looking for a way to be able to still access those subtitles on newer systems. It seems `ffmpeg` is the way to go but I'm still stuck.

Here's what I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov -map 0:s:0 -c copy -f data QT-subtitles.txt
```

gives me the plain text of the subtitles but without timestamps, so it's pretty useless for converting the subtitles to a different format.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov -map 0:s:0 QT-subtitles.srt
```

correctly converts the subtitles to SubRip including timestamps. But it gets rid of line breaks and other formatting.
It also gives me the following error messages of invalid data found:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:0 (mov_text (native) -> subrip (srt))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov_text @ 0x7fa492823200] invalid UTF-8 byte in subtitle
[mov_text @ 0x7fa492823200] Invalid UTF-8 in decoded subtitles text; maybe missing -sub_charenc option
Error while decoding stream #0:4: Invalid data found when processing input
[mov_text @ 0x7fa492823200] invalid UTF-8 byte in subtitle
[mov_text @ 0x7fa492823200] Invalid UTF-8 in decoded subtitles text; maybe missing -sub_charenc option
Error while decoding stream #0:4: Invalid data found when processing input
size=       6kB time=00:02:04.30 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s speed=3.32e+04x    
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:3kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 82.697044%
```

Suggestions from the comments below to specify `-c text` or `-sub_charenc` all give me the same results.

So, I'm hoping to find a way to extract the subtitle to a simple text file that is either still QTText-formatted (see below), or in some other way preserves linebreaks and other formatting. This is how the original QuickTime Text Track looks as text file when I extract and export it through QuickTime 7 Pro (see specs [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100103095852/http://www.apple.com/quicktime/tutorials/textdescriptors.html)).

```
{QTtext}{font:Verdana}{plain}{size:36}{textColor: 65535, 65535, 65535}{backColor: 0, 0, 0}{justify:default}{timeScale:30}{width:640}{height:116}{timeStamps:absolute}{language:0}{textEncoding:0}
[00:00:00.00]
Text here {bold} bold word {plain} text here 
[00:00:01.12]
Text here text here text here 
    Next line here (respects spaces)
[00:00:02.14]
```

I could then simply write a script to convert the formatting tags such as `{bold}` etc. to html tags, which, I believe SubRip understands.

Is there a way to specify the output format through `ffmpeg` other than having it guess what I need from the file extension such as `srt` or `txt`?  (I'm thinking in particular that if I was able to specify `mov_text` as output it might give me a QTText-formatted file like the one above ... but how would I do that?)

If `ffmpeg` can't do the job I'd be happy to try any other tools.

Comment: Have you tried including the `-sub_charenc` option as the warnings suggest?

Comment: @pigeonburger I tried `-sub_charenc UTF-8` but it gives me the error "Codec AVOption sub_charenc (set input text subtitles character encoding) specified for output file #0 (QT-subtitles-x.srt) is not an encoding option."  Do you know what I should be putting here?

Comment: It's likely using another encoding then. Try `-sub_charenc CP1250` or `-sub_charenc ISO-8859-1`?

Comment: @pigeonburger They all give me the same error message :(

Comment: The exact command I used: `ffmpeg -i test.mov -map 0:s:0 -sub_charenc ISO-8859-1 QT-subtitles-x.srt`

Comment: Try : `ffmpeg -i test.mov -map 0:s:0 -c text QT-subtitles-x.srt`

Comment: @Alain1A45 Same issue with that. I get error messages and no line breaks. Is there a way to specify the output text format directly with an option, not via file extension? (and is it possible to specify QTText?)

Comment: On windows for "LF newline style" to "CRLF newline style", in console, you can use : `more lf.txt > crlf.txt`

Comment: @Alain1A45 I'm on a Mac ... do you know what command that would be?

Comment: see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)

Comment: @Alain1A45 Oh, I see, you mean converting the resulting text file after the export from `ffmpeg`?  That doesn't give me line breaks / formatting back either. :(

Comment: Yes, this link is for LF to CRLF conversion after extracting the subtitles. For the "invalid UTF-8" problem I have no other clue without being able to test your "test.mov"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132111/discussion-between-jan-and-alain1a45).

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to transcode the mov_text subtitles to something else, (e.g. Subrip SRT files) you could try the following:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov -map 0:s:0 -c:s srt subtitles.srt
```